# Correct translation of 2 sentences

Tags: meaning, translation

I wanted to help a friend whose TV got broken in the guarantee period. I am not sure whether these are correct. We have a 2 years warranty stated in the law so I wanted to express he must prove it's less than 2 years:

> You have to take your receipt with you in order to prove you did not
>   bought it before more than 2 years (ago?).

Should be there something like "earlier" or "not later"?

And the second one - what is the english word to "accept" the guarantee complaint?

> They should accept/admit your claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence should read *You have to take your receipt with you to prove you did not buy it more than two years ago.* Alternatively, *You have to take your receipt with you to prove you bought it within the last two years.*

*Admit your claim* might be found, but it sounds rather legalistic.  *Accept* is adequate in this kind of context.